# Is programming language compulsory for HP LoadRunner?

Tags: testing, performance-testing, loadrunner, stress-testing

I am new to HP LoadRunner. Do I need to have great programming skills to use this tool? 
Or is it that I can manage this tool without havign to code or script?

Am new to to this tool. Kindly clarify me.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, you don't need to have great programming skills, But for some functionality and logic you need general programming skills. If you have little knowledge in C   like looping and file then it will enough as a beginner.

About script this tool intelligent for manage scripting activity.

Answer (score 1):

It is a foundation skill for every performance tester to be capable in the language of your tool or you will be incapable in your role

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not "great," but you definitely need some fundamental skills.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need however much programming knowledge is needed to build a simplified version of the business logic and server communication interface of your client.

The business logic complexity depends on your client and what scenarios you want to represent in the test.

There are function libraries in Loadrunner to support standard server communication protocols. If your system follows a supported communication protocol it can be as simple as calling the relevant function.

In my experience the challenge has been in understanding how the client works. That has involved more reading of code than writing of code.

Loadrunner does support quite a few languages. Off the top of my head: C, C#, Java and Javascript. At a minimum you'll need basic programming skills in one of these.